# Alternative words for disturbing in semi-formal register for emails

Tags: word-choice, word-request, politeness

I asked a few questions and sent a few emails to a customer service and  I want to begin with a kind of apologizing to my last email I will send.

I do not think it should be too formal or too apologetic but as  showing a politeness, I would like to add it.

However, using the word disturbing sounds a bit too strong for me since I have not said any rude thing on my emails and I am their customer.

What should I say then?

> I am sorry to disturb you but I need to add some information to the
> last email I sent.
>
> I am sorry to make you busy but I need to add...

Comment: If customer service is their job, you shouldn't worry about disturbing them or making them busy. You might just say "Regrettably, some information was omitted from my last email.", or "I'm sorry that some information was omitted....".

Comment: Don't use "I'm sorry".  There was information omitted in the last email.///At the very end, "We apologize for the inconvenience."

Comment: Or don't say anything at all other than *To add to my previous email,  …* You don't need to apologize, but simply provide the additional information.

Answer (score 1):

No expression is needed.

Generally, business email should use plain, simple language. Include everything that the person needs to do their job, and nothing more. Moreover, "Customer Services" will not be disturbed by your information. They are paid to be busy!

So as suggested in the comments, just start your email with "To add to my previous email..."  "I have more information to add to my previous email"

It never hurts to (briefly) thank someone for helping you, even if it’s their job to do so, at the end of an interaction. However, save apologies for when you have made an actual mistake. Excessive politeness, such as apologizing for bothering someone, can come across as insincere.